# What is -moz-padding-start and html.css ? Can't get rid of this padding

Tags: html, css

I created an `ul` in aside tag and can't get rid of `ul margins`. To be more specific, it's showing `margin_left: 40px`.
I started to check in firebug and find a html.css file that i don't have in my project.

Apparently it's overwriting some of my css rules. I tried to use `-moz-padding-start: 0;` it's not changing anything. Google results for -moz-padding-start does not show a single result.
I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried using

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

if that is not working try:

```
ul {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

if you don't want to use !important use the chrome inspector. It shows you from which files your css comes from. or tells you when it is browser generated

Comment: Thanks for help. Yes i tried `ul {margin:0; }` But that didn't hep. After checking in chrome everything was were it should be, I restarted Firefox. That did the job. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put this in your CSS:

```
ul {
   padding-left: 0px;
}
```

That works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jrKu5/1/

In general each browser does define its own set of default rules for each element, that is probably what you are running into.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `-moz-padding-start` is, I'm searching for what it is exactly. All I know is that to solve the problem just type in:

```
ul {
    -moz-padding-start: 0;
}
```

The problem, I just figured out, is a default of firefox, in other words, you know that when you have a `p` element, it already has certain defaults, like `display: block`. So what's happening is a new default of firefox.

SO you'll just have to deal with it and modify it...

and here is a link if you want to know more about it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-padding-start